# What is the difference between le savoir and ensemble de connaissances?

Tags: sens

A little help please. I am confused. What is the difference between *le savoir* and *ensemble de connaissances*? Are they interchangeable or do they overlap?

Thanks.

Comment: Voir ici: https://www.icem-pedagogie-freinet.org/node/3593

Comment: For daily usage, both can be considered as similar. When nitpicking, "le savoir" is more abstract as it may not require a clear subject or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le *savoir* is defined as *l'ensemble des connaissances* of a topic.
So in most usage it will be of similar meaning though *ensemble de connaissance* might be a longue formulation which necessitate more adjectives depending on the context, this is basically the same.

Though defintion of *le savoir* with a definite article can also refer to the sum of knowledge of all philosophers, doctors and other knowledgeable persons.
But it will heavilly rely on the context and in most context the 2 terms have the same meaning.